# How to count the file size precisely?

Tags: files-and-directories, size

This is my [`testimage.png`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQl28.jpg). My *Window 10* show its size is `1.70MB`. But I want to calculate it by *Mathematica*.

There is a new function to do this in `11.2`

```
FileSize["testimage.png"]
```

[image]

Of course I can use `FileByteCount`

```
N[FileByteCount["testimage.png"]/1024^2]
```

> `1.70172`

Since `PNG` is a uncompressed format, I think I also can use `ByteCount`

```
N[ByteCount[Import["testimage.png"]]/1024^2]
```

> `1.6995`

A slightly different result, but if you test a more larger image, the difference will be more larger. Why *Mathematica* will give us so many different results? How to count the file size precisely?

---

Ps: The Imgur cannot accept a image whose size exceed `2M`, as my test, when we count a larger image, the `ByteCount` will give a nearest result with the *Window system*.

Comment: PNG is a *compressed* (but lossless) format. You could import as `"Byte"` and then apply `Length` to get the file byte count.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov You method seem to work well for **image file** (just)..

Comment: It is just the definition of filesize, so it must work for any type of file. More info: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_size

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I mean your *... import as `"Byte"`...* method just work for image file

Comment: In Mathematica, MB means 10^6 bytes. You can convert to Mebibytes using: `UnitConvert[FileSize["testimage.png"], "Mebibytes"]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Documentation page for `FileSize` (under "Generalizations & Extensions" section),

> `FileSize` uses SI prefix values for file size, where a megabyte is 10^6 bytes

That explains the difference.

More information on the definitions for Megabyte and Mebibyte:

- https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte
- http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Megabyte.html

And as Carl Woll (Wolfram Research) points out in the [comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/157392/how-to-count-the-file-size-precisely/157397#comment419807_157392),

> In Mathematica, MB means 10^6 bytes. You can convert to Mebibytes using: `UnitConvert[FileSize["testimage.png"], "Mebibytes"]`.

Comment: You are right indeed as my test, and I recommend add your [this comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/157392/how-to-count-the-file-size-precisely#comment419807_157392) to your answer for reading

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Note that in "File properties" dialog of Windows Explorer the "File size" field reflects the actual size of the file in **Bytes**, while the "Disk space" taken by the file reflects how many bytes on disk take the **Clusters** allocated by the file.

Open the cmd.exe in administrator mode, type `Chkdsk`, and you will see how big is the **Cluster**.

[image]

There is 4096 Bytes in one **Cluster** in my `C:` disk.

In order to check the space of file has 290816 Bytes we can calculate this expr

```
Floor[FileByteCount["myPic.png"]/#]*# &[4096]

(* => 290816*)
```

Notes:

1. Different disks can have different sizes of **Cluster**.
2. Files having the "Compressed" attribute applied to them can take lesser disk space than their size.

Comment: I have corrected your formula and significantly expanded your answer. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I don't mind,thank you for improving my answer